# Problem with download multimedia plugin

Tags: package-management, connection, plugins, multimedia, visualization

When I try to play audio file then needs to install multimedia plugin, I also try to install multimedia plugin then it shows "download fail- check your internet connection. my connection speed is good, and I'm browsing web. but how to fix it?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually install the missing plugins, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav
```

This is a collection of plugins for **GStreamer**, the multimedia framework used by the default player in Ubuntu.